# Termination of patent right or utility model

Tags: patentability, claims, invalidation

I was looking up some prior art that reads, "Termination of patent right or utility model", in the LEGAL EVENT notice on the patent document. what does this mean? why would/could it say this?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Please list the patent number.

Comment: If you are looking at a document only for prior art purposes, its publication date matters but its legal status does not.